# Выбор только 12 дат между заданными датами

Tags: sql, oracle

Доброго времени суток!

Небольшая проблема с процедурами. У меня процедура которая (помимо всего прочего) вытаскивает список дат между двумя заданными датами (параметрами). Нужно сделать так, чтобы на выходе я получал все данные и даты только в кол-ве 12 штук (т.е. инфу по 12 датам начиная с даты "с"), а если между ними, например, год - даты первых чисел месяцев. Как можно это реализовать?

```
PROCEDURE GET_EXCHAGEINFO_CURRENCIES(P_DATEFROM varchar2, 
                                     P_DATETILL varchar2, 
                                     P_CURRENCIES varchar2, 
                                     RC OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
  SQL_V VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);
BEGIN
  SQL_V := 'select entr.*,
                   case when entr.ratedif>0 then 1 else 0 end DIRECTION 
            from  ( select VLT.Vltpref AS VLTNAME,
                           VLT.VLTNAME AS VLTFULLNAME, 
                           VLT.VLTCODE AS VLTCODE,
                           VLT.VLTCOLOR AS VLTCOLOR,
                           R.RATE,
                           TO_CHAR(R.RATEDATE,''DD.MM.YYYY'') AS RATEDATE,
                           R.RATE - (SELECT R3.RATE 
                                     FROM   VLT_RATES R3 
                                     WHERE  R3.vltid = r.vltid 
                                     and    r3.ratedate = (
                                            SELECT MAX(R1.Ratedate) 
                                            FROM   VLT_RATES R1 
                                            WHERE  R1.Vltid = r.vltid 
                                            and R1.RateDATE<> TO_DATE('''||P_DATETILL||''',''dd.mm.yyyy'')
                                            )
                                     ) RATEDIF             
                    FROM   VLT_RATES R 
                    left   join VLT_VALUTAS VLT 
                    ON     VLT.ID = R.VLTID
                    WHERE  R.VLTID IN ('|| P_CURRENCIES ||') 
                    AND    TRUNC(R.RATEDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('''||P_DATEFROM||''',''dd.mm.yyyy'')
                           AND TO_DATE('''||P_DATETILL||''',''dd.mm.yyyy'')

                    ORDER  BY VLT.VLTNAME,R.RATEDATE
                    )entr';
  OPEN RC FOR SQL_V;
END;
```

Comment: Невозможно ответить на вопрос не видя ваших данных и необходимого конечного результата. Сократите код до минимально необходимого для решения проблемы (т.е. уберите все поля и таблицы которые не нужны для решения задачи), после чего приведите код для создания таблиц и загрузки в них минимального контрольного примера. И к этому приложите что должно получится после выполнения запроса на приведенном примере данных

Comment: @Mike Да, наверно слишком наворочено. Я тут примерно понял как, единственное - простой вопрос: как можно выбрать каждую вторую дату между датой_с и датой_по?

Comment: Выбрать из существующих в таблице или в календаре ? т.е. если в таблице присутствуют только 1,3,10,13 января, то какие из них выбирать

Comment: @Mike Нет, есть период. Допустим с 1 по 30 число. Вернёт 30 дней, потом типа 30/12(нужных дат) = 2,5 - интервал 2 дня. Тогда взять 30 число как старт и выбрать 30, 28, 26 и тд, всего 12 (ну с погрешностью). Вот как-то так.

Comment: Тогда обычный генератор цифр и прибавлять из к стартовой дате, т.е. что то типа `select DATE '2017-05-02'+(level-1)*2  from dual connect by level <= 16`

Comment: А формулу, на что умножать level подбираете видимо да, делением длины интервала на количество